# I need to insert data into mysql from a dynamic table with selects created with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Wondering if someone could help me update mysql table with data from a couple of selects created dynamically with PHP, I have created the following code, but it seems not to be working, really appreciate your help:

```
`include_once('../includes/connection.php');`




 // Query that retrieves events
 $con = "SELECT * FROM evenement WHERE approved = 'no' ORDER BY id";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $con);
    if($con){
                    $registry =                 mysqli_affected_rows($connection);

            if($registry > 0){                      
                    echo '
                    <h1 align="center">Events pending approval</h1>
                    <br><table width="100%" align="center" border="0" border-spacing="2px" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">


                            <form action="approveReject.php" method="post" >
                                <tr bgcolor="#3333FF" style="color:white; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:15px"">
                                    <th align="center"><strong>Title</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>Details</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>Category</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>Start</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>End</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>All Day event?</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>Approved</strong></th>
                                </tr>';

                $color = "1";       
                while($registry = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    if($color==1){
                        echo '<tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8" font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:15px">';
                                $color="2";
                              } else { 
                                echo '<tr bgcolor="#dcdcdc" font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:15px">';
                                $color="1";
                              }

                            echo '
                            <form action="" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" value="'.$registry['id'].'" name="id[]" id="id">
                                <th div align="center">'.$registry['title'].'
                                <td div align="center">'.$registry['details'].'
                                <td div align="center">'.$registry['category'].'
                                <td div align="center">'.$registry['start'].'
                                <td div align="center">'.$registry['end'].'
                                <td div align="center"><select name="allDay[]" id="allDay">
                                <option value="0">Select option</option>
                                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                <option value="2">No</option>
                              </select>
                                <td div align="center"><select name="ap_re[]" id="ap_re">
                                <option value="0">Select option</option>
                                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                <option value="2">No</option>
                              </select>


                            </tr>';


                                        }

                                        ?>

                                <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" style="height:1.8em; width:7.3em;" /></td>

                                        <?php

                                        echo '</form>

                                        ';
                                    echo '


                                    </form>


                            </table>';
            }

                }else{
                echo '<h1>There are no new requests to be approved</h1>';
                }


    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

    if($_POST['allDay'] == 'Yes'){
        $allDay = 'true';

        }else{
            $allDay = 'false';
            }               
    $ap_re = $_POST['ap_re'];
    $i = 0;

    foreach($_POST['id'] as $id){   

        $udpate_qry = "UPDATE evenement SET allDay='".$allDay."', approved='".$ap_re."', WHERE id='".$id."'";
            $result_udpate_qry = mysqli_query($connection, $update_qry);
            $i++;

        }
    }
```

?>

Comment: thanks for quick answer aldanux, it was a little confusing how to add the code, but here it is.

Comment: `$udpate_qry = "UPDATE evenement SET allDay='".$allDay."', approved='".$ap_re."' WHERE id='".$id."'";` I think you need to remove the `,` for the WHERE clause.

Comment: thanks for you answer Mr. Radical, I think you are right and I should remove that, however after I did it, nothing happened, I am still unable to update my table.

Comment: Change `$result_udpate_qry = mysqli_query($connection, $update_qry);` into `mysqli_query($connection, $update_qry) OR DIE(mysqli_error());`

Comment: Change : `$udpate_qry` into `$update_qry`. Notice the dp

Comment: it didn't work either

Comment: Change: ``include_once('../includes/connection.php');`` into:  `include_once('../includes/connection.php');`. Removed backticks.

Comment: BTW all comments are incremental. Just to be clear.

Comment: I really appreciate you are taking the time helping me out, I've tried all your suggestions, but still can't get this to work.

Comment: @user3247105 do you get a error message or does everything work but the table doesn't get updated.

Comment: the table just doesn't get updated, but I get no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that I have solved all your issues, but this might help you further.

```
<?php

include_once('../includes/connection.php');


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if ($_POST['allDay'] == 'Yes') {
        $allDay = 'true';
    } else {
        $allDay = 'false';
    }

    $ap_re = $_POST['ap_re'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $i = 0;
        while ($id) {


        $update_qry = "UPDATE evenement SET allDay='" . $allDay . "', approved='".$ap_re[$i]. "' WHERE id='".$id[$i]."'";

        echo var_dump($update_qry);
        mysqli_query($connection, $update_qry) OR DIE(mysqli_error($connection));
        $i++;

    }

    header('Location: http://www.stockoverflow.com/'); // INSERT approveReject.php ???
}
 else {





// Query that retrieves events
$con = "SELECT * FROM evenement WHERE approved = 'no' ORDER BY id";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $con) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
if ($result) {
    $registry = mysqli_num_rows($result) or die (mysqli_error($connection));

    if ($registry > 0) {
        echo '
                    <h1 align="center">Events pending approval</h1>
                    <br><table width="100%" align="center" border="0" border-spacing="2px" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">


                            <form action="" method="POST" >
                                <tr bgcolor="#3333FF" style="color:white; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:15px"">
                                    <th align="center"><strong>Title</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>Details</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>Category</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>Start</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>End</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>All Day event?</strong></th>
                                    <th align="center"><strong>Approved</strong></th>
                                </tr>';

        $color = "1";
        while ($registry = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            if ($color == 1) {
                echo '<tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8" font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:15px">';
                $color = "2";
            } else {
                echo '<tr bgcolor="#dcdcdc" font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:15px">';
                $color = "1";
            }

            echo '

                                <input type="hidden" value="' . $registry['id'] . '" name="id[]" id="id">
                                <th div align="center">' . $registry['title'] . '
                                <td div align="center">' . $registry['details'] . '
                                <td div align="center">' . $registry['category'] . '
                                <td div align="center">' . $registry['start'] . '
                                <td div align="center">' . $registry['end'] . '
                                <td div align="center"><select name="allDay[]" id="allDay">
                                <option value="0">Select option</option>
                                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                <option value="2">No</option>
                              </select>
                                <td div align="center"><select name="ap_re[]" id="ap_re">
                                <option value="0">Select option</option>
                                <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                <option value="2">No</option>
                              </select>


                            </tr>';
        }
        ?>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Submit" style="height:1.8em; width:7.3em;" />

        <?php

        echo '</form>

                                        ';
        echo '


                                    </form>


                            </table>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<h1>There are no new requests to be approved</h1>';
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Mr. Radical, you are the man, I was able to update my table with your suggested code, I just needed to add $length = count($allDay) and then change the while loop to while(($id) && ($i < $length)) that made it. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @mpatino Great to hear! Could you please upvote / accept my answer?

Comment: I tried to upvote but it is telling me I have to have at least 15 reputation, so I was only able to accept the answer, again thanks very much, maybe you can see another question I have regarding retrieving data from MYSQL with check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, your update syntax might causing you the problem

```
$udpate_qry = "UPDATE evenement 
SET allDay='$allDay', approved='$ap_re' 
WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: try this
$result_udpate_qry = mysql_query($connection, $update_qry);
instead of
$result_udpate_qry = mysqli_query($connection, $update_qry);

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Radical, you are the man, I was able to update my table with your suggested code, I just needed to add $length = count($allDay) and then change the while loop to while(($id) && ($i < $length)) that made it. Really appreciate your help.